# Android - DeepLink not works if the app was started by clicking url

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using a `DeepLinkingActivity` to handle deep links and prevent it not works if the target activity is no at top.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    handleIntent( getIntent() );
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent){
    Uri data = intent.getData();

    if( data != null ) {
        final Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, LauncherActivity.class);

        if( !isTaskRoot() ) {
            newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        }

        newIntent.setData(data);
        startActivity(newIntent);
    }

}
```

I use `android:noHistory="true"` in the AndroidManifest so I don't need to call `finish()`.
It works well if the app is launched by clicking the app icon or clicking the notification.
If it's launched by clicking an url, then the deep links won't works again if I click the same url(did not call `onCreate` nor `newIntent`). But it works fine if I click others. 
That is, if click the "www.google.com" will launch my app then this url won't work again until I close my app. But "www.yahoo.com" works fine even if it was clicked more than once.

I'm using API 26, support library 26.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to the manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".DeepLinkActivity"
              android:noHistory="true"
              android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:host="www.mydomain.com"/>
            <data android:pathPattern="/page/..*/M\\..*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<activity
        android:name=".LauncherActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize">

</activity>

<activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So it won't launch second `LauncherActivity` and can be launched by clicking links.